# How to cache xsds to offload w3c servers?

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm building a web service based on SAML-P and XACML, which requires a large number of XSDs to be
considered by JAX-B/XJC for each build. This takes forever and is exceedingly unreliable, I think due to W3C throttling XSD requests to ease the load on their servers (based on their blog posting).

Worse yet, some of the W3C XSDs contain obvious typos, so these must be downloaded and patched, and the schemaLocation of referrring files edited to load the local copies. One of the primary SAML-P schema has this problem (a double >> and wildly incorrect import addresses).

I think there is a way to make Eclipse (or JAX-B, or something else; not sure what would solve this; maybe Xerces?) maintain a cache of XSDs and substitue these for http:// refs in my build (perhaps even system-wide). But I've not managed to track this down to a workable recipe. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CatalogResolver for this:

- http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Fixing_broken_references_in_schema.html